# Why are ArcGIS Online Feature Layers so Big Compared to their Source?

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-layer, file-size

I am uploading a file geodatabase to ArcGIS Online that is 40MB when unzipped. The resulting feature layer is 170MB. Why is the feature layer so much bigger than the source data? I don't remember running into this in the past. Has there been a change in the last few months?

It appears that the line geometries are taking up about 4.5 times as much space as an AGOL feature layer than as a file geodatabase or shapefile.

Comment: how are you publishing?

Comment: I tried publishing through ArcGIS Pro and through uploading the zipped FGDB and got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

If the option to Optimize Layer Drawing is enabled, it will increase the space a layer requires. Disabling it will free up the extra space.

Source: [Manage hosted feature layers](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/manage-hosted-feature-layers.htm) from the ArcGIS Online Help.

Comment: Optimize Layer Drawing is not enabled. Thanks for the response though.